# Linux kernel headers' organization

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

While I was doing some reading on system calls, I did a search for `syscalls.h` to find the header file in LXR. The search results puzzled me. There is a dozen of `syscalls.h` files coming from directories under `arch/_arch_name_/include/asm`. These are ok, they are architecture specific definitions or something else needed. The question is why do we have two different `syscalls.h` headers under both `include/linux` and `include/asm-generic`?

Also, I want to find out that what `include/linux` headers are for and what `include/asm-generic` headers are for. How do they differentiate between each other? What is the logic behind having two separate header folders? How do they relate to each other?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look inside each these files?

Comment: In /include/linux/syscalls.h, there are several system call declarations. In /include/asm-generic/syscalls.h, all system calls are declared with accompanying macro definitions. But this applies to only syscalls.h, however, i'd like to understand big picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've asked this question on [Kernel Newbies ML](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2012-March/004933.html). I got the following answer which makes things clear:

> Cihangir Akturk wrote:
>
> AFAIK, headers found in /include/asm-generic directory is for
>   architechture independent (probably shared across architectures) code.
>   Most likely you do not need to include these headers directly, instead
>   we include these headers indirectly via architecthure dependent
>   headers.
>
> OTOH, /include/linux directory is for generic header files to define
>   interfaces between components of the kernel. In most situations, you
>   will find all the kernel functionalities you need in these headers.
>
> regards, chngr.

Answer (score 1):

The headers in directories `arch/_arch_name_/include/asm` are specific architecture dependent, such as for x86, ARM architectures. So the logic inside is platform-specific and highly depends on the underlying hardware. You will only include what your platform architecture is.

Headers in `include/linux` are common and platform independent. They're common logics and will be shared cross architectures.

Comment: The other question is what is the reason of having include/asm-generic in addition to include/linux headers? What is the relation between them?

Comment: My opinion is `include/asm-generic` provides a common and uniform interface to access hardware-related data structure. `include/asm-generic` allows developers control the underlying hardware much easier and no need to dig out the hardware spec detail.

For example, `include/asm-generic/rtc.h` provide a uniform interface to retrieve rtc information, but its implementation includes architecture-dependent code, such as `CMOS_WRITE` and `CMOS_READ`.